# Bash command or script to produce phrase analysis of text files

Tags: bash, text

I have built a script that downloads an entire site into a folder.  I now want to build a script that will take a file as input, or a list of words as input, and then scan all the files in the folder (recursively) and output the phrase with the number of times the phrase is found. I'd like to be able to give it a list of phrases eg ["first phrase", "second phrase"]

Example output:

"first phrase", 52
"second phrase", 4

I'm using this command to search all the files in a directory, and its outputting the files where the phrase is found.  How would I then modify this, or pipe it into another command so that I can count the total number of times?

> grep -rnw ./ -e "backup"

Answer (score 1):

You meant the total count ?

```
grep -rnw ./ -e "backup" | wc -l
```

Comment: Will that give me the total count of the phrase?  or just the total count of files that contain the phrase?  I'm trying to get the total count of the phrase accross all the files.

Comment: it counts the total no of lines in your output i.e newline separated strings.

Comment: It counts the number of lines which contain the phrase, not the number of occurrences of the phrase. And you could get that count without `wc`, using the `-c` option. If you want the number of occurrences of the phrase, you need the `-o`  option, but then you do need to pipe through `wc` because `-c` is always the line count, even with `-o`.

Comment: So using `-o` & piping it through `wc -l` works, right?

Comment: so the total command to get the number of occurrences of the phase would be:

> grep -rnwo ./ -e "bakcup" | wc -l 

as the total command?

Comment: And here's a really rookie question for you as a follow-on.  Will grep return multi word phrases?  eg if after the -e I have "backup software" will it search on that properly?